# Unable to merge dex still appear after enabling multiDex

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dex

All solutions i found were enable multiDex i tried it but didn't work 
another solution was enable it and add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'` but didn't work too

The Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "recipe.bakes.bakesrecipe"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.2.jar'

)
}
```

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use multiple same dependency for your project. You need to use only one of gson.

Remove the gson jar from your **libs** directory and from `build.gradle` dependencies. Your dependencies block should be something like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    //implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.2.jar')
}
```

For your current dependencies block, you don't really need multidex.